# The problem of Spark tasks not being processed in parallel

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I used Spark to read the tables in hive for preprocessing, and then use it for machine learning. With the same set of code, I train different categories of products, creating a model for each category. Each Spark task is assigned 40 executors, 10g, and 20 cores. The same hive table (not a Partition table) is read in the preprocessing phase of each model task, and the data of different  categories. is filtered through the field "category". Allocate 807 tasks and process a data volume of 60 million. Models in other categories can run multiple tasks in parallel for each executor, with only one in the "mobile" category

[image]

Why can other categories handle the same code, data source, and resource allocation in parallel, while the "mobile" category can only execute one task per executor at the same time.